# Redmine in Japanese

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am a newbie to redmine.
I have a requirement with redmine.
On change of language in Administration->Settings->Display->Languages from English to Japanese is not working.Infact none of the other languages are working.
I want the whole redmine to be translated to japanese.
My default language is English.
Please explain me how to change it to Japanese and display the whole redmine in japanese

Comment: Please define "not working". "Not working" as in "Redmine stops working", or as in "the language doesn't change"?

Comment: It works fine for the redmine installed in the server .. But i have another redmine installed in my local machine .. It does not work in my local RedMine .

Answer (score 1):

Go to 'My Account' from upper right corner and set 'Default language' to Japanese and save.

Answer (score 1):

**Administration->Settings->Display->Default Language** applies only to newly created accounts.

You'll also need to change the language of all the existing accounts, including the admin user.